# How to use correctly in Android the permission REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS to allow the GeofenceAPI working also during doze?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-geofence, doze

I have an Android App using the Geofence API

```
val intent = Intent(contextProvider.context, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contextProvider.context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val builder = GeofencingRequest.Builder()  
builder.setInitialTrigger(initialTrigger)
addGeofences(builder) // in this function I have the code to add one or more geofences
geofencingRequest = builder.build()
```

The code works fine and I get the method onReceive called in my broadcast receiver, if the device is not idle. During idle periods, the device doesn't react at all.

I tried to add in the manifest the permission `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` and in another place I call the code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    val powerManager = context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val packageName = context.applicationContext.packageName
    val ignoringOptimizations = powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)

    if (!ignoringOptimizations) {
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
        context.startActivity(intent)
    } 
}
```

and if I didn't already allowed to ignore the battery optimization I can see the dialog asking for that. I don't see any difference in the behaviour of the app.
In order to check if the new permission works, I have a background thread logging every second the value of a counter:

```
Single.fromCallable {
    var counter = 0
    do {
        Timber.i("#$counter")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    } while (counter++ < 120)
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe({
    Timber.i("onSuccess")
},
    {
        Timber.e("onError: $it")

    })
```

This is the kind of logging that I get:

```
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:27:662 :    - #1
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:28:674 :    - #2
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:29:683 :    - #3
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:30:693 :    - #4
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:31:700 :    - #5
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:32:707 :    - #6
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:33:719 :    - #7
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:40:008 :    - #8
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:41:018 :    - #9
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:47:42:036 :    - #10
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:48:55:449 :    - #11
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:48:56:457 :    - #12
Mi. Apr. 17 2019 at 13:48:57:471 :    - #13
```

You can notice, that at the beginning every second there is a new output, then there are some lags. I assume this lags are because of the idle mode. I get similar logs with and without battery optimization.

My app uses also a foreground service that should avoid the app going idle, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

At the end I have two questions:

1- how should I use the permission to ignore the battery optimization, in order to see an effect on the app?

2- are there better approaches in order to manage geofences while the device is idle?

Thanks!

Comment: What geofence events do you expect while dozing? The device is, by definition, not moving.

Comment: The device is actually moving in my pocket, but because of doze it cannot detect the movement. My goal would be to avoid entering the doze mode (I would explain my users why I need to keep the device awake and then they can decide if they are interested in the functionality I'm offering)

Comment: @Filippo Where you able to solve this issue? I'm on a similar situation, the ENTER geofences sometimes don't trigger or I have experimented the trigger after 2 hours of being inside the geofence. Using Android 8.0 here.

Comment: @fernandospr unfortunately not